# How to inspect Angular components in Chrome using Augury when in production mode?

Tags: angular, web-inspector, augury

I'm going to be doing a presentation on Angular 6 soon and want to show component trees and how components work together. **Would I be able to show this while I'm viewing a website such as Santander's site?**  I tried viewing the site using Augury, but it stated that it was in production mode and cannot be viewed.

> This application is running in production mode and therefore cannot be
>   inspected using Augury. If this is an Angular application, please
>   rebuild your application in debug mode or remove the call to
>   enableProdMode().

Comment: **Please rebuild your application in debug mode** `ng build`

[Read More here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#production-optimizations)

Comment: you can rebuild it using 'ng build' command

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance. You want me to use the cmd to type ```ng build```? I'm just confused as to where to rebuild the website. If it was a applicatoin i built on my own i'd know exactly what your talking about. but this is a web app that i typed into the chrome search bar. Sorry, just wanted clarification as to where to type ng build

Comment: if I gather correctly. If you are trying to show component trees of someones website using Augury then the answer is "No". If it is your website then we can show comp trees, routing structure, etc..